# Cancel all outstanding QTimer events

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am looking for a way to setup a number of timed function calls in pyqt, with a way to cancel all pending calls when needed.

I was looking at using `QtCore.QTimer` to setup the function calls, but I don't know of any good way to cancel these calls.  Any ideas?

I can't seem to find any way to cancel after using `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.function)`.   If instead I create a list of `QTimer` objects I can stop them, but then I am forced to manage a list of timer objects (creation, deletion, which are active, etc.), which I would like to avoid.

```
# Setup a timer object.
timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
timer.timeout.connect(self.function)
timer.setSingleShot(True)
timer.start(1000)

# To stop the timer object at some later point.
timer.stop()
```

I could also manage my own queue of pending function calls, which I would also like to avoid if possible (for the sake of simplicity).

Here is some dummy code showing the kind of thing I am trying to do:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Test(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        

    def addDelayedCall(self, time, function):
        # Do something here.
        pass


    def clearPendingCalls(self):
        print('  Clearing pending function calls.')
        # Do something here.


    def setupCalls(self):
        self.addDelayedCall(500, self.dummy)
        self.addDelayedCall(1000, self.dummy)
        self.addDelayedCall(1500, self.dummy)
        self.addDelayedCall(2000, self.dummy)


    def dummy(self):
        print('dummy just got called.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    test = Test(app)

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, test.setupCalls)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1250, test.clearPendingCalls)
                   
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, app.quit)            
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have come up with a solution by directly using the timer functionality provided by `QObject`.  I suspect that there is a more elegant solution, but this will probably work for what I need.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class Test(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)

        self.timers = {}


    def timerEvent(self, event):
        function = self.timers.pop(event.timerId())
        self.killTimer(event.timerId())
        function()


    def addDelayedCall(self, time, function):
        timer_id = self.startTimer(time)

        self.timers[timer_id] = function


    def clearPendingCalls(self):
        print('  Clearing pending function calls.')

        while self.timers:
            timer_id, function = self.timers.popitem()
            self.killTimer(timer_id)


    def setupCalls(self):
        self.addDelayedCall(500, self.dummy)
        self.addDelayedCall(1000, self.dummy)
        self.addDelayedCall(1500, self.dummy)
        self.addDelayedCall(2000, self.dummy)


    def dummy(self):
        print('dummy just got called.')




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    test = Test(app)

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, test.setupCalls)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1250, test.clearPendingCalls)

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, app.quit)            
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: An easier way to do this would have been to use `QTimer` as before, but drop the convenient `setSingleShot` in lieu of creating and configuring QTimers explicitly. *But*, instead of maintaining a list manually, all you need to do is maintain a vanilla `QObject` somewhere, and *use that QObject as the parent of the QTimer instances you make* (e.g. `QtCore.QTimer(cancellerObject)` -- you don't need to hold on to the QTimer instances yourself after that. Then to cancel all pending timers, just destroy that object, and it will destroy all its child QTimers immediately as a side effect.

Comment: @JasonC, this sounds like a good approach and is indeed much simpler than my solution.  I'll have to play around with this and consider it for future projects.

Answer (score 2):

you can [disconnect](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#disconnect) from the timer's timeout signal and connect back whenever you need. Once disconnected you stop receiving any calls from the timer even though it still remains active. Below is a small example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("button", self)       
        self.button.resize(100, 30)

        self.connect(self.button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.on_button_click)

        self.connected = True
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.connect(self.timer, QtCore.SIGNAL('timeout()'), self.on_timeout)
        self.connect(self.timer, QtCore.SIGNAL('timeout()'), self.on_timeout_test)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def on_button_click(self):
        if self.connected:
            self.disconnect(self.timer, QtCore.SIGNAL('timeout()'), self.on_timeout_test)
        else:
            self.connect(self.timer, QtCore.SIGNAL('timeout()'), self.on_timeout_test)
        self.connected = not self.connected

    def on_timeout(self):
        print 'on_timeout'

    def on_timeout_test(self):
        print 'on_timeout_test'

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

once timer started both slots `on_timeout` and `on_timeout_test` are getting called, when you click the *button* `on_timeout_test` slot gets disconnected and then connected back if *button* is clicked again.

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help for what I am trying to do. (It's a great solution for what it does though.)  I added some dummy code to my question which hopefully explains more clearly what I am going for.